# QGIS Server 2.18 GetPrint doesn't wait for XYZ tiles

Tags: qgis, qgis-2, qgis-server

I am trying to generate a PDF output with a Print Composer using QGIS Server 2.18. The map includes a couple of layers from local shapefiles, and also an XYZ Tile Server layer.

QGIS Server does not seem to wait for the XYZ Tiles to load when generating an output. The Composer template loads correctly and so do all the layers based off shapefiles on the server's file system. But the XYZ tiles from the external site simply do not render at all. This happens in both the GetMap and GetPrint requests.

If I spam refresh on the GetPrint request several times, the XYZ do load. I believe that under the heavier load, the XYZ tiles do load in time to be included in the output. And once they have been loaded once, they seem to cache and will load on all subsequent requests.

Is there anything I can do to ensure that QGIS Server will wait for the XYZ tiles to load every time before returning the result of the GetPrint request?